# Points in the tetrahedron

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

There is a regular tetrahedron with edge ledge of $2$ units. Your task is to put as many points within the volume occupied by the tetrahedron.

But there is a condition: there has to be at least $1$ unit distance between each points.

> What is the maximum number of points you can put within the tetrahedron with the condition above?

*Note that* edges and vertices of tetrahedron are considered within the volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you can do anything better than

> choosing the points at the vertices of the tetrahedron, and halfway each edge

resulting in

> 10 points.

(I don't have a proof, it's just mathematical intuition, based on [Sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing).)